# ImageResizer downloads an image multiple times?

Tags: imageresizer

I followed this article: http://imageresizing.net/blog/2013/effortless-responsive-images.

My images are stored on a CDN and after installing all the nuget packages, I got resizing to work, but the problem I ran into was that I had to add style="max-width:100%" to most of the images.

Also, I have a page where the same image appears in multiple spots and I guess Image Resizer thinks that this these spots should contain different sizes of the image, so it downloads 3 different versions which sort of defeats the purpose. Is this how it is supposed to work naturally?

As an example, I have imageA.png on a page and it might be in the top, middle, and bottom.  Image Resizer is downloading a different version for each section.

What is the best way to use imageresizer with srcset? I can't seem to find any thing on it.

If I use the DiskCache plugin, will this serve images to other users that request the same size or is it just for the current user requesting it?

Comment: > style="max-width:100%" to most of the images 

If an image appears in multiple spots, and those spots require differently sized/cropped versions of the image, there will be multiple requests. This is how it is supposed to work. DiskCache is not per-user. It is a global cache. It does re-apply authorization rules before serving from the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to break apart your 4-question question.

> style="max-width:100%" to most of the images

CSS like `img {max-width:100%}` can do this globally. This rule is present by default in many themes/frameworks.

If an image appears in multiple spots, and those spots require differently sized/cropped versions of the image, there will be multiple requests. This is how it is supposed to work.

ImageResizer responds to URLs like "image.jpg?width=100" Just use those URLs as you would when using srcset normally. [Here's the webkit demo](https://webkit.org/demos/srcset/).

DiskCache is not per-user. It is a global cache. It does re-apply authorization rules before serving from the cache.